# Аналог (подобие) include в C#

Tags: c#, include

(Просьба не удалять вопрос. Четко сформулированного нет.)

Как выделить в отдельные файлы свои структуры и классы!? Чтобы потом можно было

```
using MyClass.sharp;
```

или как-то по-другому...

**UPD**
Для наглядности:

Файл My.cs  с пользовательскими (собственными, новыми) классами:

```
namespace MyNumClasses //Мои классы
{

    public class MyNumClass //мой класс
    {
        public MyNumClass()
        {
        }
    }

}
```

Как бы я ни делал не помогает using MyNumClasses. Пишет ошибку!!!

```
using My.cs;
using MyNumClasses;
```

Не работает никак.
Может быть файл нужно куда-то положить?

Основной файл "Form1.cs":

```
....
using System.Net;//WebClient
using MyNumClasses;
....
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{


    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public MyNumClass tttest;
        public string sMessage = "NULL";  
....
```

> Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен "MyNumClass" (возможно, отсутствует директива using или ссылка на сборку)

Comment: добавь скрин solution explorer в котором видны оба твоих файла. И скрин, в котором видны два твоих файла и ошибка.

Comment: @Grundy Моего файла там нет!!!  Как раз и думал, что следовало бы. Не знаю почему автоматом не включила его студия. Как вручную сделать?

Comment: правой кнопкой на проекте, Add -> Existing Item -> выбираешь свой файл

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо, всё работает!!! Добавь 4м пунктом это, твой ответ засчитаю.  4. У кого не работает, добавить вручную  Add -> Existing Item -> выбираешь свой файл

Comment: ты можешь свой ответ написать, с указанием что делал и почему ошибка была

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Grundy, публикую полный ответ:

В C# using работает не так как include в C++. using не делает импорт конкретного класса, а целый namespace.

1. Создать новый файл (например, My.cs)
2. Скопировать структуру/класс (см вопрос).
3. Добавить файл в решение:
   В обозревателе решений пкм Добавить->Существующий элемент (Add -> Existing Item) -> выбираешь свой файл
4. В месте использования добавить строку, которая будут импортировать namespace:

```
using MyNumClasses;
```

5. Еще добавлю, что в этом файле нужно дублировать директивы using из основной части!!!
   Вот только тогда и получиться полноценный include!!!

Comment: у вас уже 2 похожих ответа, и вы дублируете 3й....по моему как то не правильно.

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц, оба нерабочие!!! И мой тоже. Вывел свой класс в отдельный файл, подключил его и получаю ошибку, используя stringArg.IsNullOrEmpty()  `Отсутствует аргумент, соответствующий требуемому формальному параметру "value" из "string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)".`

Comment: так у вас получилось в итоге?

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц,в итоге да!!! Но лучше чем C++ include просто нет, видимо. Я так любил отдельно держать чисто свои классы!!! А тут даже сделав все 4 пункта всё равно можно накосячить. Ужас.

Comment: @СаакШахламджян, как ты создавал файл?

Comment: @Grundy всё получилось, но пришлось дублировать директивы using (5й пункт). Создавал через файл-Создать файл-Класс Visula C#. Это неправильный способ?

Comment: @СаакШахламджян, а надо было правой кнопкой на проекте -> add -> new item

Comment: @Grundy это для того, чтобы файл был в Обозревателе решений. Он добавлен вручную! Но всё равно директив не хватает. Если описываемый класс использует функции для string из nuget расширений, его пришлось отдельно скачать к этому файлу... И указать using WebSocketSharp; Или такого быть не должно?

Comment: @СаакШахламджян, стоит почитать [книги по c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/186999) - там описывается что, как и для чего

Comment: @СаакШахламджян я думаю создание библиотеки с вашими классами было бы для вас хорошим выходом с данной ситуации....вам нужно 1) Написать либу 2) Подкинуть ее в любую прогу(указать в ссылках) 3) Если речь идет о c#, то подключить в `using` и юзать функционал.

Answer (score 4):

В C# `using` работает не так как `include` в C++. `using` не делает импорт конкретного класса, а целый [namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/).

1. Создать новый файл
2. Скопировать структуру/класс
3. В месте использования добавить строку, которая будут импортировать `namespace`.

Например:

Class.cs

```
namespace XXX
{
    public class Class { }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
using XXX; // using может быть не нужен, если оба класса находятся в одном namespace.

namespace YYY
{
    public class Program { } // тут вы сможете использовать свой класс
}
```

Comment: Что-то не получается. Не "видит".  Что делал: 1) Создал новый файл в проекте (выбрал в конструкторе файл-класс). 2) Сохранил как MyNum.cs  3) Внутри "namespace MyNum"  4) Не работает using MyNum; или using MyNum.cs   Что-то не так делается, чего-то не хватает... И полный путь пытаюсь указать, вообще кучу ошибок пишет

Comment: @СаакШахламджян, где ты пишешь `using MyNum;`?

Comment: @СаакШахламджян есть еще проще вариант...вы просто пишете "правильно" название метода в пространстве, где он не виден. Потом `ПКМ` по ошибке => `Быстрое действие и рефакторинг` => один из пунктов будет `подключить using ***` (Проверено только в студии)

Comment: @Grundy в файле Form1.cs, "в основной" части. После остальных деректив using. Пишет "Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен "MyNum1" (возможно, отсутствует директива using или ссылка на сборку)"            Хотя я как раз и пишу using ...

Comment: @СаакШахламджян, почему ты пишешь `MyNum1` если выше в комментарии писал `MyNum`?

Comment: @Grundy, сорри, пример переписал. Сейчас апдейт сделаю.

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть класс, который находится в конкретном `namespace`, например:

```
namespace MyApp.Data
{
    public class MyDataClass
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Для того чтобы создать этого экземпляр этого класса в другом файле проекта, вам потребуется "подключить" его с помощью `using` указав `namespace`, в котором находится нужный вам класс, например:

```
using MyApp.Data;

namespace MyApp.Main
{
    public class MainClass
    {
        public void Method()
        {
            var data = new MyDataClass();
        }
    }
}
```